# removeClass with conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you `click` either image a unique `modal` appears for each.

I used a function that hides the apple modal if you click away.

How do I keep the apple modal showing if I click any of the `.alt-btn`'s?

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (
    $(".apple-modal").hasClass("active") &&
    !$(".modal, .modal *, .button").is(e.target)
  ) {
    $(".modal").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```js
$("[data-close]").click(function(e) {
  const dataClose = $(this).attr("data-close");
  const elem = $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]').length ?
    $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]') :
    $(dataClose);
  if (elem.hasClass("active") && elem.is(":visible")) {
    elem.removeClass("active");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  const id = $(this).prop("id");
  $(".modal").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active", $(this).data("id") == id);
  });
});
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (
    $(".apple-modal").hasClass("active") &&
    !$(".modal, .modal *, .button").is(e.target)
  ) {
    $(".modal").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.header {
  height: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 72px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.modal:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  top: -6px;
  right: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

.modal.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.dignitasteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" class="button test" id="google" data-close="google" />
<img src="https://www.arabianbusiness.com/sites/default/files/styles/full_img/public/images/2017/01/17/apple-logo-rainbow.jpg" class="test button" id="apple" data-close="apple" />
<div class="modal" data-id="google">
  <div class="header">Google</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal apple-modal" data-id="apple">
  <div class="header">Apple</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="alt-btn">Keep Open</button>
<button class="alt-btn">Keep Open</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add '.alt-btn' here:

```
if ($(".apple-modal").hasClass("active") &&
    !$(".modal, .modal *, .button, .alt-btn").is(e.target))
{
    if(!$(".apple-modal").hasClass("keep-active"))
        $(".modal").removeClass("active");
}
```

Here is working example:

```js
$("[data-close]").click(function(e) {
  const dataClose = $(this).attr("data-close");
  const elem = $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]').length ?
    $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]') :
    $(dataClose);
  if (elem.hasClass("active") && elem.is(":visible")) {
    elem.removeClass("active");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  const id = $(this).prop("id");
  $(".modal").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active", $(this).data("id") == id);
  });
});
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (
    $(".apple-modal").hasClass("active") &&
    !$(".modal, .modal *, .button, .alt-btn").is(e.target)
  ) {
    $(".modal").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.header {
  height: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 72px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.modal:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  top: -6px;
  right: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

.modal.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.dignitasteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" class="button test" id="google" data-close="google" />
<img src="https://www.arabianbusiness.com/sites/default/files/styles/full_img/public/images/2017/01/17/apple-logo-rainbow.jpg" class="test button" id="apple" data-close="apple" />
<div class="modal" data-id="google">
  <div class="header">Google</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal apple-modal" data-id="apple">
  <div class="header">Apple</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="alt-btn">Keep Open</button>
<button class="alt-btn">Keep Open</button>
```

EDIT: ==>

It is not an issue. I thought you need to close it when opener button is second time pressed. If you don't need to close then you have to remove.

```
data-close="apple"
```

from

```
<img src="https://www.arabianbusiness.com/sites/default/files/styles/full_img/public/images/2017/01/17/apple-logo-rainbow.jpg" class="test button" id="apple" data-close="apple" />
```

see the code example below:

```js
$("[data-close]").click(function(e) {
  const dataClose = $(this).attr("data-close");
  const elem = $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]').length ?
    $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]') :
    $(dataClose);
  if (elem.hasClass("active") && elem.is(":visible")) {
    elem.removeClass("active");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  const id = $(this).prop("id");
  $(".modal").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active", $(this).data("id") == id);
  });
});
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (
    $(".apple-modal").hasClass("active") &&
    !$(".modal, .modal *, .button, .alt-btn").is(e.target)
  ) {
    $(".modal").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.header {
  height: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 72px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.modal:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  top: -6px;
  right: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

.modal.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.dignitasteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" class="button test" id="google" data-close="google" />
<img src="https://www.arabianbusiness.com/sites/default/files/styles/full_img/public/images/2017/01/17/apple-logo-rainbow.jpg" class="test button" id="apple" />
<div class="modal" data-id="google">
  <div class="header">Google</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal apple-modal" data-id="apple">
  <div class="header">Apple</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="alt-btn">Keep Open</button>
<button class="alt-btn">Keep Open</button>
```